# Wordpress - image formats & name conventions

Tags: wordpress, image-processing

I have added a couple of new image formats to my Wordpress site but I now would like to force a naming convention.

So far I have this in functions.php:

```
add_image_size( "maximal", "1900" );
add_image_size( "desktop", "1400" );
add_image_size( "tablet", "1024" );
add_image_size( "mobile", "500" );
add_image_size( "minimal", "10" );
```

This results in producing images with this type of name:

```
[domain_name]/wp-content/uploads/sites/[date]/[name]-300x102.jpg
```

I would like to get rid of the 300x102 part and replace it with the name I gave in the functions.php file

In the end, what I would like to get is:

```
[domain_name]/wp-content/uploads/sites/[date]/[name]-minimal.jpg 
[domain_name]/wp-content/uploads/sites/[date]/[name]-mobile.jpg
[domain_name]/wp-content/uploads/sites/[date]/[name]-tablet.jpg
```

...etc...

Is there a way to force Wordpress to use a different name convention?

The idea behind this is to load the smallest format by default to avoid affecting load time too much, then detect the resolution with JS and load the most appropriate format. If I don't have a name convention, I won't be able to replace the small picture by a bigger one.

Thanks
Laurent

Answer (score 0):

The name used on the first param of the function add_image_size just a label for you to retrieve specific sizes when displaying your images. For example:

`the_post_thumbnail( 'maximal or desktop' );`

Comment: yes I know but I'd like to change the filename too. The idea is too load always the smallest format and then if I detect a higher resolution, I load a better picture but changing its name in JS.